# I do not understand why PostgreSQL indicates that a procedure does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, procedure

I have a strange problem with PostgreSQL. It indicates that a procedure does not exist while I think that I created it. I really do not understand. I tried to remove arguments only to see if I would have the same problem or another one but I still got the same problem...

Here is my code :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clients, accounts, transactions, failed_transactions CASCADE;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client int,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(id),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    amount float
);

CREATE TABLE failed_transactions
(
    id serial,
    account_id integer,
    attempted_amount float,
    timestamp timestamp DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_failed_transaction(new_line record, old_line record)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF new_line.balance<-500 THEN
        INSERT INTO failed_transactions(account_id, attempted_amount)
                    VALUES (new_line.id, new_line.balance-old_line.balance);
    END IF;
END $$;



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER accounts_update BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_failed_transaction(NEW, OLD);

INSERT INTO clients VALUES (10, 'Client 1');
INSERT INTO clients VALUES (14, 'Client 2');
INSERT INTO clients VALUES (25, 'Client 3');

INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (8, 2000, 14);
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (12, 650, 10);
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (2, 300, 25);
```

Comment: Your procedure is called transactions with s ar the end

Comment: You need a function, not a procedure. See als the manual: `In the syntax of CREATE TRIGGER, the keywords FUNCTION and PROCEDURE are equivalent, but the referenced function must in any case be a function, not a procedure.`

Comment: By the way, the syntax for your function (not a procedure) is also wrong, it can't take input parameters and must return a trigger. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

First, a trigger needs to call a trigger *function*, not a procedure. But there is nothing that keeps you from writing a PL/pgSQL trigger function that `CALL`s the procedure of your liking.

It may be confusing that `CREATE TRIGGER` allows this syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ... EXECUTE { PROCEDURE | FUNCTION } ...
```

However, this is a syntactical leftover from the time before PostgreSQL had procedures. Back then, the only allowed syntax was `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`, even though it called a trigger function. With the advent of procedures, this became rather odd, so the new and now preferred syntax `EXECUTE FUNCTION` was introduced, but `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` is still allowed for compatibility reasons. Still, you can only call a function, not a procedure.

---

The other problem with your code is that you are trying to pass arguments to the trigger function in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. You *can* pass arguments, but they have to be string constants and are accessed via the special variable `TG_ARGV` in the trigger function (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER)). You have to define the trigger function **without** arguments. `OLD` and `NEW` are available in the trigger function of a row-level trigger without the need to explicitly pass them.

Comment: Thank you but I do not know what I have to do now. I tried to replace the procedure by a function and it made the same error...

Comment: I see (and now answered) the other problem in your code. I cannot comment on your changed code and the error you get with it, because I cannot see it.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you. I managed to correct my code and advanced in my work but I have another problem. Then, I think that I will create a new topic.